# Group outcome of an Array

Tags: php, arrays, group-by

I have multiple arrays which I would like to display ordered in categories. Each item has a category and sometimes even a sub category...

First Array:

```
public 'title' =>
    array
        'value' => 'Consultant'    
public 'field_job_category' => 
    array
        'value' => string 'Professional Services Applications'
public 'field_job_sub_category' => 
    array
        'value' => string 'Microsoft'
```

Second Array:

```
public 'title' =>
        array
            'value' => 'Consultant'    
public 'field_job_category' => 
        array
            'value' => string 'Professional Services Applications'
public 'field_job_sub_category' => 
        array
            'value' => string 'Apple'
```

...

```
public 'title' =>
        array
            'value' => 'Engineer'    
public 'field_job_category' => 
        array
            'value' => string 'Business Partner'
public 'field_job_sub_category' => 
        array
            'value' => string ''
```

And I would like to group the arrays like this:

> Professional Services Applications (category)
>       - Microsoft (sub category)
>       - Apple (sub category)
>
> Business Partner (category)
>       - (no sub categories)

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Am I asking for the impossible?

Comment: no just curius what is `public` in front of array

Comment: No this should be possible if I am understanding the question correctly. You would like to order a multi-dimensional associative array?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear as your code does not really make sense but I will give it a go.

I assume your parent array looks like this:

```
$categories = array(
    'Professional Services Applications' => array(
        'Microsoft',
        'Apple'
    ),
    'Business Partner' => array()
);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct. But I don't know the names of the (sub)categories in advance... I'll try to rewrite my code in a second.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like you need to use a foreach loop to create an associative array. Then, once created, you can re-order it and merge certain parts together if necessary. Post what you haev and what you want to end up having and I will write it for you

Comment: @Michiel Wow!! Is that php?????? I will do my best to make sense of it but it is in a very weird format!

Comment: That's a dump of the Array I would like to order. But, yes. It's generated by PHP (Drupal => maybe that will make more sense :))

Comment: @Michiel Ahhhh, I see, you are using the STD Object! Okay, now I can understand all the publics and formats etc

Comment: @Michiel It is horribly confusing. Are you able to use `print_r()` on the relative array or is this all you have access to?

Comment: Nope, I can do a print_r() too, but I think it won't help you much... I'm stripping the print as we speak

Comment: @Michiel Can you also state what information you have in the first place and how this array is built?

Comment: I don't think you'll have any benefits on seeing the `print_r()` since it's the same output as the `var_dump`. The big dump you see is what I get from an 3th party API.

Comment: @Michiel Do you have access to the PHP or are you simply executing everything via API. For instance, can you do this: `print_r($object->'field_application_url');` I need to have a clearer understanding of how you are accessing the data. If you want to access this associative array, how are you doing that?